# How to run this SQL query of wp_terms database

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables (only pertinent info included for brevity and clarity)

Table Name: wp_term_relationships

```
object_id    term_taxonomy_id
1266         1341
1266         452
1266         449
```

Tabloe Name: wp_term_taxonomy

```
term_taxonomy_id    term_id
1341                1342
452                 453
449                 450
```

Table Name: wp_terms

```
term_id      name      slug
1342         792       792
453          396       396
450          394       394
```

I have a list of the wp_term "names" and I want to get a list of the object_ids (only unique ones) from wp_term_relationships

So, my list will be something like: 394, 396, 988, 666
And I would like it to return (based on the above data): 1266
(i.e. Using term_id from wp_terms to get term_taxonomy_id from wp_term_taxonomy and then finally using that value in wp_term_relationships to get the object_id)

I am quite new to mySQL and have been reading/experimenting with it all day and can't seem to get it quite right.

```
SELECT $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
FROM $wpdb->term_relationships
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id   
WHERE name IN (394, 396, 988, 666)  
GROUP BY $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
ORDER BY $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id DESC
```

I wondered if someone could maybe cast an experienced eye over it and help me see where I'm going wrong?

Thank you :-)
This is my query so far:

Comment: Please explain **why** you want to do it that way. It could be that you are facing a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Is your term data _actually_ numeric? That is pretty unconventional case, could you elaborate on what are you doing with it? Typically API functions are easier in WP than raw SQL.

Comment: You basically have it - just `GROUP BY $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id` instead.

Comment: @bonger thanks that sorted it. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it. kaiser / Rarst, unfortunately I have inherited this db and have to work with what I've got but your link to the x/y problem was a very interesting read. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments, you basically have it - just `GROUP BY $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id` instead; also to be pernickety, you'd use standard (INNER) JOINs rather than LEFT ones:

```
SELECT $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
FROM $wpdb->term_relationships
    JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
    JOIN $wpdb->terms ON $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id   
WHERE name IN (394, 396, 988, 666)  
GROUP BY $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
ORDER BY $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id DESC
```